# why does my python asyncio queue always block on queue.get() on two diff threads?

Tags: python, flask, queue, python-asyncio

I want emit some data when url "/data" on flask-based web app. The queue on the fun data() has put("data111") and put("data222"), but `package = await queue.get()` can never get the put-element, just blocking. Why? Help.

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)
queue = asyncio.Queue()


@app.route("/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def index():
    return render_template("data.html")


@app.route('/data')
async def data():
    await queue.put("data1111")
    await queue.put("data22222")
    return "dsjkfl"


def run_flask():
    app.run()


async def flask_queue_emit():
    print("flask_queue_emit begin running")
    while True:
        package = await queue.get()
        print("flask_queue_emit --- queue data:", str(package))
        # Perform other processing operations
        queue.task_done()
        print("flask_queue_emit #########")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
    flask_future = executor.submit(run_flask)
    queue_future = executor.submit(asyncio.run, flask_queue_emit())

    try:
        while True:
            pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        flask_future.cancel()
        queue_future.cancel()
        executor.shutdown(wait=False)
```

I try many methons by ask ChatGpt, but sadlly nothing works.

Comment: Did you remember to run
`pip install "Flask[async]"`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could you please provide a more detailed description as I am still not familiar with Python and cannot find the information you mentioned about 'flask [async]'

Comment: Type that command to your shell.  How did you get flask onto your computer?

Comment: I do run 'pip install "Flask[async]"', but problem still exist. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

An asyncio.queue will not work across different asyncio loops - you have to use a traditional, cross-thread, `queue.Queue` there.
Putting elements on an unbound queue is not a blocking operation - only if you want to limit it's size you will have to worry about it (maybe creating an asyncio.queue and an extra worker, in the same thread as the producers, to pop things from the async queue and put it into the threaded queue, if there is room).

Also, even if that works in dev-mode, you have to pay attention that when setting it up for production your application server (uvicorn, gunicorn, etc) is not configured to use multiprocessing at all: an item put in such a queue in one process will never be seem in another process. using multiprocessing.Queue is not an option as the queue object have to be carefully distributed across running workers- and one does not get that level of control under the application server.

Also, you have a potential "HeisenBug" there in that you create a thread pool executor and submit two "perpetual" tasks to it: it will likely always succeed, but that is not the object of Pool executors: a submitted task will *eventually* run when there is an open spot. You; d better create two deterministic threads with threading.Thread`.

Eventually when you need this to work across different processes, I suggest using a queue backed by an external manager such as `redis`.  At that point you can even put your queue processing in a worker that is not related to the flask application at all - but that is not needed.

If that is the present/future of A.I. code generation, I am not impressed at all. This is hard to debug code, and you, the one trying to run it, have no idea of what it is trying to do - it may be cheaper to hire a proper professional person.